# Block incoming traffic in bonding mode when primary interface is down

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, bonding

My server running on latest kernel (4.4.6) has configured a bond device (**bond0**) with two enslaved interfaces **eth0**, **wlan0** with primary interface **eth0**.

```
cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0 
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: eth0 (primary_reselect always)
Currently Active Slave: wlan0
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 1000
Up Delay (ms): 1000
Down Delay (ms): 1000

Slave Interface: wlan0
MII Status: up
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 3
Permanent HW addr: dc:53:60:5f:50:cd
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: down
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 4
Permanent HW addr: b8:ae:ed:7c:7d:c9
Slave queue ID: 0
```

I run also iptables to filter traffic and block some local ports while I allow all outgoing traffic.

```
*filter
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8090 -j ACCEPT
```

What I have fail to do is to create a mechanism when the primary interface **eth0** is down and the **wlan0** is getting active to block the remote access on specific port.

I tried to add an iptable rule for **wlan0** while I know that is not correct because the interface is **bond0** **(Failed)**

```
*filter
-A INPUT -p tcp -i wlan0 -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8090 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8090 -j ACCEPT
```

I tried to add an iptable rule for **wlan0** to mark packets on preroute and catch on filter **(Failed)**

```
*mangle
-A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff
*filter
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8090 -m mark ! --mark 0x1 ACCEPT
```

I tried to add an ebtable rule to mark packets on Layer2 and catch on Layer3  filter **(Failed)**

```
EBTABLE
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p ipv4 -i wlan0 -j mark --set-mark 0x1 --mark-target ACCEPT

IPTABLE
*filter
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8090 -m mark ! --mark 0x1 ACCEPT
```

I would like to avoid the MAC address solution because it will not work on Mac Policy: None

Any Ideas?